# how to separate a string into multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove the part that is equal to `ID` from `Name`, and then build three new variable which equal to the last two digit of `Name`, the 3 place in `Name', and 4th place in` Name". sth that will look like the following:

[image]

What should I do in order to achieve this goal?

```
df<-structure(list(Name = c("LABCPCM01", "TUNISCN02", "HONORCN01", 
"KUCCLCN02", "LABCPBF03", "LABCPBF04", "MFHLBCM01", "MFHLBCF01", 
"DRLLBCN01", "QDSWRCN03", "QDSWRCN04", "UTSWLHN01", "MGHCCBN02", 
"JHDPCHM01", "UNILBCF03", "UTSWLGN03", "PHCI0CN01", "PHCI0CN02"
), ID = c("LABCP", "TUNIS", "HONOR", "KUCCL", "LABCP", "LABCP", 
"MFHLB", "MFHLB", "DRLLB", "QDSWR", "QDSWR", "UTSWL", "MGHCC", 
"JHDPC", "UNILB", "UTSWL", "PHCI0", "PHCI0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_remove` and then create the 'var' columns with `substr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(New_Name = str_remove(Name, ID), 
          var1 = readr::parse_number(New_Name), 
          var2 = substr(New_Name, 2, 2), 
          var3 = substr(New_Name, 1, 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 6
   Name      ID    New_Name  var1 var2  var3 
   <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1 LABCPCM01 LABCP CM01         1 M     C    
 2 TUNISCN02 TUNIS CN02         2 N     C    
 3 HONORCN01 HONOR CN01         1 N     C    
 4 KUCCLCN02 KUCCL CN02         2 N     C    
 5 LABCPBF03 LABCP BF03         3 F     B    
 6 LABCPBF04 LABCP BF04         4 F     B    
 7 MFHLBCM01 MFHLB CM01         1 M     C    
 8 MFHLBCF01 MFHLB CF01         1 F     C    
 9 DRLLBCN01 DRLLB CN01         1 N     C    
10 QDSWRCN03 QDSWR CN03         3 N     C    
11 QDSWRCN04 QDSWR CN04         4 N     C    
12 UTSWLHN01 UTSWL HN01         1 N     H    
13 MGHCCBN02 MGHCC BN02         2 N     B    
14 JHDPCHM01 JHDPC HM01         1 M     H    
15 UNILBCF03 UNILB CF03         3 F     C    
16 UTSWLGN03 UTSWL GN03         3 N     G    
17 PHCI0CN01 PHCI0 CN01         1 N     C    
18 PHCI0CN02 PHCI0 CN02         2 N     C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of lapply and str_split to get the parts that do not contain the same values in ID, and then you can use substring from there.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(new_name = unlist(lapply(str_split(Name, ID), function(f) f[[2]]))) %>%
  mutate(var1 = substring(new_name, 4, 4),
         var2 = substring(new_name, 2, 2),
         var3 = substring(new_name, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
R> df <- data.frame(f1=as.factor(c("LABCPCM01","TUNISCN02", "HONORCN01", "KUCCLCN02"))) 
R> tidyr::separate(df, f1, sep=c(5,6,7), into=c("ID", "var3", "var2", "var1"))


     ID var3 var2 var1 
1 LABCP    C    M   01 
2 TUNIS    C    N   02 
3 HONOR    C    N   01 
4 KUCCL    C    N   02
```